# Copy files from Linux Server to Windows - bash script

Tags: linux, windows, scp, sftp, file-transfer

i am trying to automate a simple process, but i m new and stuck. I have a number of bash scripts that when ran, zip and move files to specific directories on the linux box. I want to create a bash script that will transfer said files to a specific disk of a windows box on the same network. 
IE :

From Linux Box : XXXX@10.11.10.11
To Windows Box : XXXX@12.12.12.12

I ve seen several commands that can do this, i would like this done by a batch script so that i can implement some simple controls on what was moved succesfully and so on. Which of these tools should i use?

ssh / sftp / scp

Or should i prefer some solution like Winscp

Comment: Another solution is to create a Windows share and mount it into Linux, and setup a simple copy script on the Linux side onto the mounted share.

Comment: @mazs : OP uses very different sample IPs in his post. This suggests (to me) that both boxes will probably not reside in the same subnet, or that OP specifically wants a solution where it does not matter. CIFS connections can be established across network boundaries, true, but that can become complex too. OP: Can you clarify in your Post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need an SSH Server running in your Windows box, in order to do it this way. AFAIK [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction) is only client, which means that your script should run in your windows box and copy the files *from* your linux box.

I would use something like [Bitvise SSH Server](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server?gclid=CjwKEAjwpLa5BRCTwcXS6_rpvC4SJACTDQMM2kZN8gL8ID30T_lOoA-StCK-lm6enC4pw67fxTbisBoCfFnw_wcB), exchange ssh keys between windows and linux boxes and, run the script in linux (with scp) as you planned.

Comment: Bitvise is not free, and costs 100$ per year. It seems to use a self-written, non-auditable crypto-backend written by <10 people. They have a pretty good security track record though considering. This answer could use some updating, and a different (first) product recommendation to be useful for people in the same situation as OP, imho. NotYet+1

Comment: @AlexStragies Bitvise SSH Server can be used free of charge by non-commercial personal users.